# how to setup routes, controller, and views the proper way in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I just started playing around with laravel. First of all, this is the best framework i've came across. Now here is my issue. I am trying to point from routes -> controller -> view

```
//This is my Controller file

 public function index()
{
    return View::make('pages', array('name' => 'Taylor'));
}

 // This is my Routes File
Route::get('/', 'pagesController@index');

View file => pages.blade.php
```

This is the error i'm getting.

```
FatalErrorException in pagesController.php line 19:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it seems that the problem is that the `View` class is not found in the current namespace.

Try this way:

```
//use the View class from the global namespace
return \View::make('pages', array('name' => 'Taylor'));
```

or import the `View` class at the beginning of the controller's script:

```
use View;
```

Comment: Yes!! It worked. Thanks for that, but my question is, why does it need the path ?

Comment: because the file's current namespace is `App\Http\Controllers` and Laravel searches the classes' files in the current namespace, if you don't specify otherwise. I suggest you to check how  [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) works in PHP

Comment: @HimanshuBatra: consider accepting the answer if it's usefull ;)